# SQLite Android multiple selectionArgs for one selection parametr

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I now there are similar questions here, but I can't figure out what to do by them, I got following code

```
 Cursor getterCursor = null;

    String selection = "topic" + " =? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"topic1", "topic2"};

    getterCursor = questionsDatabase.query(mDBName, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

And it returns an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.`. I understand that it happens because I got two elements in array selectionArgs, but I have completely no idea how to make it work right, help please. 
One more time: I really tried to solve it by myself following the  guides from internet and from SO in particular, but I could not handle it, so now asking for help here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your objective to return data if `topic` is either `"Тут тема будет"` or `"тема математики"`?

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, that's right, btw sorry for another language, changed name of parametrs to english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want results for 2 vaues of `topic` then use the operator `IN`:

```
String selection = "topic IN (?, ?)";
```

This is equivalent to:

```
String selection = "topic = ? OR topic = ?";
```

Comment: ok, got it, thank you! may you please also tell me how code should looks like if I don't know hom much parametrs will be in array?

Comment: Then you need a `for` loop to construct a string like: `(?, ?, ?, .....)` with as many `?` placeholders as the number of items in the array.